# Flutter logger is getting called twice

Tags: flutter, dart, logging

I have a `CustomLogger` class to which I pass a `Logger` object. Now whenever I call logger method from the `CustomLogger` class the logs are printed twice. I have created this CustomLogger class as I am planning to send these logs to server and don't want to call separate method for it.

This is the where I am creating object of `CustomLogger` class

```
var logger = CustomLogger(
  logger: Logger(
    printer: PrettyPrinter(
      methodCount: 0,
      errorMethodCount: 5,
      colors: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is my `CustomLogger` Class

```
class CustomLogger {
  Logger logger;

  CustomLogger({
    @required this.logger,
  });

  /// Log a message at level [Level.debug].
  void d(dynamic message, [dynamic error, StackTrace stackTrace]) {
    logger.d(message, [error, stackTrace]);
  //TO Do : send log to server
  }
}
```

When i call `logger.d("test log");` , it first prints `null` and then prints the log

```
 ┌────────────────────────────
 │ [null, null]               
 ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
 │  test log     
 └────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured why it is printing `[null,null]` after a lot of debugging and went through the library code. It is actually the `error` argument.

`logger.d` has `message` as required positional argument and `error`, `stackTrace` as optional, so when we call `logger.d(message,[error,stacktrace])` the error argument becomes [error,stackTrace] and it is printing that `error` which is `[null,null]`.

So right way to call `logger.d'` from wrapper class is `logger.d(message,error,stackTrace)`.